# Simulate bounceInDown easing effect from animate.css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

I'm writing a slot machine game and I have code similar to this: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/imsy041/2t48xmtk/)

```
$('#test').css( "margin-top", 7400px );
$('#test').animate(
    {"margin-top": "0px"},
    {'duration' : 3000, 'easing' : $.bez([0,0,0.9,1.1])}
);
```

I'm not satisfied with the result. It just doesn't seem smooth at the end. Is there any library that has the easing effect like the one from animate.css? The bounceInDown effect from animate.css just move from outside the frame which I cannot control(I think?). The elements in the game that I'm writing has to move from one point to other. I tried the easeOut effect that comes with jquery too but again I'm not satisfied with it.

Comment: Why you don't use animate.css then?

Comment: I need to move the element from one point to other. Whereas animate.css's bounceInDown effect only move from outside the frame to the location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to smoothly **bounce**, I suggest to use multiple **keyframes** (since your current animation is limited by just end keyfrome and one bezier function), but unfortunately **jQuery's animate() does not support multiple keyframes.** So I would recommended to use CSS for this. Or check out some additional libraries for that like [jQuery.Keyframes](https://github.com/Keyframes/jQuery.Keyframes).

Just imagine keyframes as steps or states between the start keyframe and end keyframe:

[image]

If you like the animation of **animate.css** just have a look what they do in their animation (I removed prefixes to shorten this coding).

```
@keyframes bounceInDown {
  from, 60%, 75%, 90%, to {
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
  }

  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, -3000px, 0);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate3d(0, 25px, 0);
  }

  75% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
  }

  90% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 5px, 0);
  }

  to {
    transform: none;
  }
}
```

Just get inspired by it and maybe change it to your favor.

Comment: I understand how keyframe works, but what is the meaning of cubic bezier  from above? --- from, 60%, 75%, 90%, to { animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000); } --- this is the part that I don't understand

Comment: Actually this is just a shorthand for
``from {
   animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
}
60% {
   animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
}`` ... and so on – and for keyframed animations, the timing function applies between keyframes rather than over the entire animation.
And if you don't know how a cubic bezier function works, it's similar to a normal bezier function, but whereas bezier functions are quadradic functions, the cubic one is cubic. Maybe take a look at http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-cubic-bezier/.